# Residuals from a mixed effect model

Tags: residuals, multivariate-regression, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm running a beta-binomial mixed effects model that estimates the effect size (B) and partitions variance into a random effect (g) and error (e). I would like to calculate the residuals (e), but only have values for the fixed effects and the proportion of variance explained by the random effect and error term (a & b respectively). Because of the data, model, and software (MACAU) I am using, the only outputs are the parameters and it will not produce the residuals or vector of random effects directly.

How can I calculate the values of e?

`Simplified model: Y ~ Bin(N,pi); log(pi/1-pi) ~ xB + g + e 
    Where Y represents a n-by-1 matrix, g(i)...g(n) is distributed MVN(0,aK), and e(1)...e(n) ~ MVN(0,bI). Within g and e, a and b are constants, K is a covariance matrix within the data, and I is the identity matrix.`

An indirect solution would be to calculate the values of g and then back-calculate e from the observed values. However, I'm unsure how to calculate values of g that could be used.

Comment: In general a linear mixed effects model is of the form $y \sim N(X\beta, Z D_\gamma Z^T + \sigma^2 I)$ you can re-express it as $y|\gamma \sim N(X \beta + Z \gamma, \sigma^2 I)$. In your case this means that your conditional fitted values $\hat{y} = X \hat{\beta} + Z \hat{\gamma}$. As such your residuals conditional to the estimated $\hat{\gamma}$ are simply $\epsilon = y- \hat{y}$. Do you use a particular piece of software for this analysis? eg. R's `lme4::lmer` or `nlme::lme`?

Comment: I'm using MACAU which runs a beta-binomial model, not a linear mixed effects model. What you're getting at in the rest of your question is what I allude to at the end of mine: there is the same problems with estimating γ as with estimating ϵ making it difficult to do ϵ=y−y^ (which would be very easy!)

Comment: Please, add that information in your main post. The fact you use a non linear model is an integral part of your question. Also please add the link function you use and all other information that one would need to fully asses the question.

Comment: Sure thing, I've done so now (I think).